# Trouble printing items from a List of Lists of Objects

Tags: c#, list

I've got an assignment which requires me to create products and services and add them to a package (a list). each package will then be added to a list of packages.

I managed to create packages of one service and one product each but I'm having trouble printing the list as it will print all items within each package as many times as there are packages (ex if I add 3 packages it will print each product and service 3 times). I'm stumped as to what to do.

I ran the debugger and it shows that the `q in p` `foreach` is running 4 times instead of 2 but I have no idea how to fix this.

Here is my code from the `Package` class:

```
public class Package : AbstractProduct,IPackageble, IEnumerable, 
{

    public static List<AbstractProduct> package_elements = new List<AbstractProduct>();

    public bool canAddToPackage(Package package)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void Add_element(AbstractProduct elem)
    {
        package_elements.Add(elem);
    }

 public override string Description()
    {
        foreach (AbstractProduct f in package_elements)
        {
            String var = " ";
            var = prod.Description();
        }
        return var;
    }
```

And the `AbstractProductManager` class:

```
public abstract class AbstractProductMgr
{
    //The general list

    protected static List<Package> elements = new List<Package>();

    public static void WriteToConsole()
    {
        foreach(Package p in elements)
        {
          foreach (AbstractProduct q in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q.Description());
            }
        }
    }
```

`AbstractProduct` is an abstract class which defines the attributes for a product/service and a virtual `Description` method which lists them. The class is inherited by a `Service` and a `Product` classes, which override the `Description` method with any specific attributes.

The products/services are read from the keyboard in their own manager classes. A `PackageMgr` class calls the insertion methods for products/services and adds them to the Package list then adds the `Package` list to the `Elements` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
public static List<AbstractProduct> package_elements = new List<AbstractProduct>();
```

which means that `package_elements` are shared between all instances of the `Package` class. You probably want to loose the `static` modifier:

```
public List<AbstractProduct> package_elements = new List<AbstractProduct>();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I ran the debugger and it shows that the q in p foreach is running 4 times instead of 2 but I have no idea how to fix this.

Remove the inner loop because the `Package` class will go though all its items and print them. I commented it out.

```
foreach(Package p in elements)
{
        // foreach (AbstractProduct q in p)
        //{
        Console.WriteLine(p.Description());
      //  }
}
```

You should also make the `package_elements` private or else things can be added to it from outside.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will.
I tried that inner loop thing but it did not work. BartoszKP was correct. the static was the problem. I just did not see it.

Comment: Yes BartosKP is right about the static. However, since your package class iterates its own items you should just call `Discription` on it the way I have shown.